# Cloropleth using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, maps, visualization

I've been trying to plot a cloropleth map. I've made some progress, but I'm stuck now.
The idea is to plot the map of Brazil and color code each state bases on the number of violent intentional deaths in 2021.

I'm using the following dataset:

```
State <- c("SP", "SC", "DF", "MG", "RS", "MS", "PR", "AC", "PI","TO", "MT", "RO", "GO", "RJ", "ES", "MA", "PB", "AL", "RN", "PA", "SE", "PE", "RR", "CE", "AM", "BA", "AP")
VID <- c(7.9, 10.1, 11.2, 11.4, 15.9, 20.7, 20.8, 21.2, 23.8, 24.3, 24.9, 25.0, 26.1, 27.2, 28.2, 28.3, 28.6, 31.8, 32.4, 32.8, 33.9, 34.8, 35.5, 37.0, 39.1, 44.9, 53.8)
VIDBrazil <- data.frame(State, VID)
```

The geoJSON data file from Brazil I'm sourcing from this [Brasil JSON file](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/thiagobodruk/brazil-geojson)

The code I'm trying to use is based on resources found [here](https://r-graph-gallery.com/), especially [here](https://r-graph-gallery.com/327-chloropleth-map-from-geojson-with-ggplot2.html), [here](https://r-graph-gallery.com/choropleth-map-in-r.html), [here](https://r-graph-gallery.com/325-background-map-from-geojson-format-in-r) and [here](https://r-graph-gallery.com/169-170-basic-manipulation-of-shapefiles)

The code I'm using is the following:

```
State <- c("SP", "SC", "DF", "MG", "RS", "MS", "PR", "AC", "PI","TO", "MT", "RO", "GO", "RJ", "ES", "MA", "PB", "AL", "RN", "PA", "SE", "PE", "RR", "CE", "AM", "BA", "AP")
VID <- c(7.9, 10.1, 11.2, 11.4, 15.9, 20.7, 20.8, 21.2, 23.8, 24.3, 24.9, 25.0, 26.1, 27.2, 28.2, 28.3, 28.6, 31.8, 32.4, 32.8, 33.9, 34.8, 35.5, 37.0, 39.1, 44.9, 53.8)
VIDBrazil <- data.frame(State, VID)

spdf_Brasil <- geojson_read("C:/Users/Giovanni/Desktop/R/brazil_geo.json", what = "sp") #Import JSON file

spdf_Brasil_A<- tidy(spdf_Brasil) #Convert to data frame

ggplot() + #plot the map
  geom_polygon(data = spdf_Brasil_A, aes( x = long, y = lat, group = group), fill="#69b3a2", color="white") +
  theme_void() +
  coord_map()

spdf_Brasil_MVI <- spdf_Brasil_A %>% #add the values of deaths to use for color coding the map
  left_join(. , VIDBrazil, by=c("id"="State"))


ggplot() + #ploting with color coding
  geom_polygon(data = spdf_Brasil_MVI, aes( x = long, y = lat, group = group, fill= VID), color="green") + 
  theme_void() +
  scale_fill_gradient(name = "Mortes por 100 mil habitantes", low = "#fdc0b2", high = "#9a1f03", limits = c(0, 60.0)) +
  coord_map()
```

[Obtained map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Waku.png)

What am I missing? What should I do to get the map color coded?

Thank you for your assistance!

Comment: check your data, the VID column is all NAs, since when joining the data the id column doesn't have the state names

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`id` field in GeoJSON is not handled by `broom::tidy()` as-is, so there are no State codes in the resulting data frame and join will not work as intended. Though the column named `id` is still there, thus `left_join()` will not throw an error.   If you check your `spdf_Brasil_MVI`, you may notice that all `VID` values are `NA`s. And instead of State codes, `id` column includes numeric values stored as characters:

```r
glimpse(spdf_Brasil_MVI)
#> Rows: 581,207
#> Columns: 8
#> $ long  <dbl> -73.33251, -73.27482, -72.87016, -72.69151, -72.65935, -72.18967, -72.17318, -…
#> $ lat   <dbl> -7.324879, -7.350334, -7.528882, -7.610621, -7.624979, -7.720489, -7.723841, -…
#> ...
#> $ id    <chr> "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1"…
#> $ VID   <dbl> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA…
```

Using `sf` package for handling spatial data and ggplot's `geom_sf()` layer for plotting sf objects simplifies this quite a bit:

```r
library(sf)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
VIDBrazil <- data.frame(
  State = c("SP", "SC", "DF", "MG", "RS", "MS", "PR", "AC", "PI","TO", "MT", "RO", "GO", "RJ", "ES", "MA", "PB", "AL", "RN", "PA", "SE", "PE", "RR", "CE", "AM", "BA", "AP"),
  VID = c(7.9, 10.1, 11.2, 11.4, 15.9, 20.7, 20.8, 21.2, 23.8, 24.3, 24.9, 25.0, 26.1, 27.2, 28.2, 28.3, 28.6, 31.8, 32.4, 32.8, 33.9, 34.8, 35.5, 37.0, 39.1, 44.9, 53.8))

sf_Brasil <- st_read("brazil_geo.json", as_tibble = TRUE, quiet = TRUE)
# sf object, a data.frame / tibble with all features (id, name) + geometry column
# and projection details:
sf_Brasil
#> Simple feature collection with 27 features and 2 fields
#> Geometry type: MULTIPOLYGON
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: -73.98971 ymin: -33.74708 xmax: -28.84694 ymax: 5.264878
#> Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
#> # A tibble: 27 × 3
#>    id    name                                                           geometry
#>    <chr> <chr>                                                <MULTIPOLYGON [°]>
#>  1 AC    Acre             (((-73.33251 -7.324879, -73.27482 -7.350334, -72.8701…
#>  2 AL    Alagoas          (((-35.90153 -9.861805, -35.90153 -9.862083, -35.9012…
#>  3 AP    Amapá            (((-50.02403 0.859862, -50.02403 0.859306, -50.02347 …
# ...

p1 <- ggplot(sf_Brasil) +
  geom_sf(fill="#69b3a2", color="white") +
  theme_void()

sf_Brasil_MVI <- left_join(sf_Brasil, VIDBrazil, by = join_by(id == State))
# join result, includes VID values:
sf_Brasil_MVI
#> Simple feature collection with 27 features and 3 fields
#> Geometry type: MULTIPOLYGON
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: -73.98971 ymin: -33.74708 xmax: -28.84694 ymax: 5.264878
#> Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
#> # A tibble: 27 × 4
#>    id    name                                                     geometry   VID
#>    <chr> <chr>                                          <MULTIPOLYGON [°]> <dbl>
#>  1 AC    Acre             (((-73.33251 -7.324879, -73.27482 -7.350334, -7…  21.2
#>  2 AL    Alagoas          (((-35.90153 -9.861805, -35.90153 -9.862083, -3…  31.8
#>  3 AP    Amapá            (((-50.02403 0.859862, -50.02403 0.859306, -50.…  53.8
# ...

p2 <- ggplot(sf_Brasil_MVI) + 
  geom_sf(aes(fill = VID), color="green") +
  scale_fill_gradient(name = "Mortes por 100 mil habitantes", low = "#fdc0b2", high = "#9a1f03", limits = c(0, 60.0)) +
  theme_void() +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")

p1;p2
```

[image][image]

For labelling sf objects we could use `geom_sf_label()` or `geom_sf_text()`, but when things can get bit crowded and it's not so easy to fit all labels, `geom_label_repel()` & `geom_text_repel()` form `ggrepel` package are worth considering.

```r
library(ggrepel)

# add layer to existing p2 plot
# get coordinates for geom_label_repel from sf_coordinates stats
# name : column in p2 data (sf_Brasil_MVI) 
# geometry : geometry column of p2 data (sf_Brasil_MVI)
p2 + geom_label_repel(aes(label = name, geometry = geometry),
                      stat = "sf_coordinates")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-03-12 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Adding to this question. How can I find the center of each Brazilian state to add a label? And how to add the label efficiently?

Comment: You can add `geom_sf_label()` or `geom_sf_text()`  layer to ggplot and don't really need to worry about state centroids as this is where those functions place labels / text by default, though you'd get centroids with `sf::st_centroid()`.  Depending on the output size and resolution it can get bit crowded and you might want to move labels from actual centroids, this is where `ggrepel` package with `geom_label_repel()` / `geom_text_repel()` becomes handy, but to use it with geom_sf involves dealing with stats. I'll add another example.